# List all the certificates under a azure app service

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli, azure-appservice, azure-rest-api

How to get the list of certificates under an Azure App service using either Azure CLI or REST API with thumbprint and expiration details?

[image]

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: `az webapp config ssl list` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/ssl?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-config-ssl-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using Azure CLI

***List SSL certificates for web applications.***

To build a list of SSL certificates in Azure CLI.

```cs
az webapp config ssl list --resource-group MyResourceGroup
```

[image]

To display the details of a web app's SSL certificate.

```cs
az webapp config ssl show --resource-group MyResourceGroup --certificate-name cname.mycustomdomain.com
```

[image]

### Using REST API

Get all certifications for a subscription

```cs
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates?api-version=2021-02-01
```

[image]

and with optional parameters

```cs
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates?api-version=2021-02-01&$filter={$filter}
```